# Как запускать задание в crontab 1 раз в 2 недели

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

Сервер Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Задача в corn записана след образом

```
sudo crontab -e
* 23 * * * cd /path/to/dir && /path/to/python/env/python3 /path/to/dir/one_day.py
```

Как запускать задание 1 раз 2 недели?
(Каждый вторник 2,4 недели месяц)

Comment: У вас [сейчас](https://crontab.guru/#*_23_*_*_*) скрипт запускается каждый день 60 раз: в 23:00, 23:01, 23:02,.. 23:59.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации crontab](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/cron/crontab.5.en.html) есть такой пример. Запуск каждую вторую субботу месяца:

```
# Run on every second Saturday of the month
0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
```

Адаптируем этот пример к вашим данным, получим следующее. Запуск каждый второй и четвертый вторник месяца:

```
# Run on every second and fourth Tuesday of the month
0 4 8-14,22-28 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 2 && echo "2nd or 4th Tuesday"
```

Comment: у вас суббота пропала

Comment: Спасибо!
Надеюсь подойдет